# Parameter value not being passed in xslt call-template

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Fairly new to XSLT and saw the with-param as a way to get something done.

```
        <xsl:variable name="PQB_ID">
         <!-- <xsl:value-of select="wd:SSN"/> -->
           <xsl:value-of>123</xsl:value-of>
         </xsl:variable>

         <xsl:call-template name="testing">
                 <xsl:with-param name="PQB_ID"></xsl:with-param>
         </xsl:call-template>
```

And my template name is below:

```
<xsl:template name="testing">
   <xsl:param name="PQB_ID"></xsl:param>
   <xsl:value-of select="$PQB_ID"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>
```

At a minimum, I would expect to see 123. Or, when  my `<xsl:value-of select="wd:SSN"/>`  is uncommented, I would expect to see the value in my program.  As it is, I get nothing back.

What am I missing?

Comment: You happen to have a variable and a template parameter that use the same name. Specifying `<xsl:with-parameter name="PBQ_ID"/>` does not assign it a value. As @Ian Roberts points out, you need to select the vale to assign to the parameter when you call the template.

Answer (score 6):

```
<xsl:with-param name="PQB_ID"></xsl:with-param>
```

will pass an empty value for the parameter. If you want to pass through the value of the global PQB_ID variable, you need to do so explicitly

```
 <xsl:with-param name="PQB_ID" select="$PQB_ID"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also, it's a really good idea in XSLT 2.0 to declare the type of the expected parameter in xsl:param. Are you expecting a string? an integer? I don't expect you are expecting a document node, which is what you are carefully creating with the code

```
 <xsl:variable name="PQB_ID">
   <xsl:value-of>123</xsl:value-of>
 </xsl:variable>
```

If the template wants an integer, then you don't need a whole new document to contain it; just write

```
<xsl:variable name="PQB_ID" select="123"/>
```